# How would I fix this JTextArea formatting error?

Tags: java, swing, file, text, jtextarea

I am working on a simple file reader. It reads the .txt file then formats the output and displayed the output in a JTextArea. For some reason, the output does not display correctly. I have given my current code, followed by the text file contents below.

**Code**

```
public static JTextArea display = new JTextArea();

public static void main(String[] args) {

        // GUI

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Haberdasher");
        frame.setSize(450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(null);
        frame.setContentPane(container);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(display);
        scroll.setBounds(10, 10, 415, 150);

        container.add(scroll);

        frame.toFront();
        frame.setVisible(true);


        // Logic


        String path = "src//employees.txt";

        boolean endOfFile = false;

        String output = "Name" + "\t\t" + "Weekly Sales" + "\t\t" + "Weekly Pay" + "\n";

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while (!endOfFile) {

                String name = br.readLine();

                if(name == null) {
                    endOfFile = true;
                } else {
                    int sale = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                    if(name.length() >= 16) {
                        output += name + "\t" + sale + "\t\t" + "300" + "\n";
                    } else {
                        output += name + "\t\t" + sale + "\t\t" + "300" + "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            br.close();
            System.out.println(output);
            display.setText(output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

**employees.txt Contents:** http://hastebin.com/ijuyedizil.nginx

**Current Output:**[image]

**Expected Output:** http://hastebin.com/epesipatot.nginx

Comment: either don't print the whole name or use another tab

Comment: You have to make the number of tabs (\t) you print dependent  on the length of the strings you are printing.

Comment: What is your expected output? Is that alignment issue is the problem ?

Comment: Thank you for the help. The issue is the alignment, apologies for not specifying; I have added the expected output.

Comment: I have edited the question. Now, the output is fine in the console, but not in the JTextArea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, the output is fine in the console, but not in the JTextArea.

If you want the text to align like it does on the console need to use a monospaced font

```
textArea.setFone( new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 10) );
```

You may also need to use:

```
textArea.setTabSize(...);
```